# Check if variable is a specific interface type in a typescript union

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

Is it possible to create a typeguard, or something else that accomplishes the same purpose, to check if a variable is a specific interface type in a typescript union?

```
interface Foo { a:string }
interface Bar { b:string }

(function() {
    function doStuff(thing: Foo | Bar) {
        if(typeof thing === 'Foo') {
            console.log('Foo');
        } 
        else if (typeof thing === 'Bar') {
            console.log('Bar');
        }
        else {
            console.log('unknown');
        }
    }

    var thing: Foo = {a:'a'};
    doStuff(thing);
})();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`typeof` doesn't do this. It always return "string", "number", "boolean", "object", "function", or "undefined".

You can test for object properties with a test like `if(thing.a !== undefined) {` or `if(thing.hasOwnProperty('a')) {`.

Note that you could make an object that had *both* a string `a` and a string `b`, so be aware of that possibility.

Comment: So there's no way to check if a variable conforms to an interface without checking specific properties (like 'a' in our example)?

Answer (score 24):

Since Typescript 1.6 you can use user-defined type guards:

```
let isFoo = (object: Foo| Bar): object is Foo => {
    return "a" in object;
}
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: The big one answer here is that `'key' in object` is understood by TypeScript as a way to tell interfaces apart. Sadly `typeof object.key === 'undefined'` fails in this case.

Comment: A problem with this approach is that if `a` is renamed to `aa`, the code will still compile, even if `a` is no longer a discriminator for the `Foo` interface.  Actually, it might be better not to use a type guard and just do an inline member check with `in`. Then the compiler will infer the type - as long as `a` is part of `Foo`.  Anyone got a more type safe approach to this?

Comment: @JørgenTvedt That's the main problem indeed. I'm very interested by a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript 2 you can use [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) like this:

```js
interface Foo {
    kind: "foo";
    a:string;
}
interface Bar {
    kind: "bar";
    b:string;
}
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
let thing: FooBar;
```

and then test object using `if (thing.kind === "foo")`.

If you only have 2 fields like in the example I would probably go with combined interface as [@ryan-cavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704166/ryan-cavanaugh) mentioned and make both properties optional:

```js
interface FooBar {
    a?: string;
    b?: string
}
```

Note that in **original** example testing the object using `if (thing.a !== undefined)` produces error `Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'.`

And testing it using `if (thing.hasOwnProperty('a'))` doesn't narrow type to `Foo` inside the `if` statement.

[@ryan-cavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704166/ryan-cavanaugh) is there a better way in TypesScript 2.0 or 2.1?

Comment: This is the safest way to get compiler checks on unions, IMO, and the best way to handle OP's problem. I think this is the best answer now @myartsev