# Why does 'instanceof' in TypeScript give me the error "'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."?

Tags: javascript, typescript, instanceof

I wrote this code

```
interface Foo {
    abcdef: number;
}

let x: Foo | string;

if (x instanceof Foo) {
    // ...
}
```

But TypeScript gave me this error:

```
'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Why is this happening? I thought that `instanceof` could check whether my value has a given type, but TypeScript seems not to like this.

Comment: See the answer below @4castle. Otherwise, you're right, I'll make it `Foo | string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)

Comment: And possible duplicate of [Check if variable is a specific interface type in a typescript union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172486/check-if-variable-is-a-specific-interface-type-in-a-typescript-union) (I don't really want to single-handedly hammer this)

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly, now that's definitely a duplicate of a Possible duplicate!

Answer (score 211, accepted):

### TL;DR

`instanceof` works with classes, not interfaces nor type aliases.

---

### What's TypeScript trying to tell me?

The issue is that [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is a construct from JavaScript, and in JavaScript, `instanceof` expects a *value* for the right-side operand.
Specifically, in `x instanceof Foo` JavaScript will perform a runtime check to see whether `Foo.prototype` exists anywhere in the prototype chain of `x`.

However, in TypeScript, `interface`s have no emit. The same is true of `type` aliases. That means that neither `Foo` nor `Foo.prototype` exist at runtime, so this code will definitely fail.

TypeScript is trying to tell you this could *never* work. `Foo` is just a type, it's not a value at all!

If you're coming from another language, you might have meant to use a class here. Classes *do* create values at runtime, but there are some notes about that that you may want to read about below.

### "What can I do instead of `instanceof` if I still want a `type` or `interface`?"

You can look into [type guards and user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

### "But what if I just switched from an `interface`  to a `class`?"

You might be tempted to switch from an `interface` to a `class`, but you should realize that in TypeScript's structural type system (where things are primarily *shape based*), you can produce any an object that has the same shape as a given class:

```
class C {
    a: number = 10;
    b: boolean = true;
    c: string = "hello";
}

let x = new C()
let y: C = {
    a: 10, b: true, c: "hello",
}

// Works!
x = y;
y = x;
```

In this case, you have `x` and `y` that have the same type, but if you try using `instanceof` on either one, you'll get the opposite result on the other. So `instanceof` won't *really* tell you much about the type if you're taking advantage of structural types in TypeScript.

Comment: So basically I didn't get the idea from the answer which is better to go with. Class? because you detailed it. But confused at the same time as you mentioned "you maybe tempted".  So what if I have to compare all properties and not just swim property as in docs for type guards?

Comment: The main point here is that `instanceof` works with classes, not interfaces. Thought that needed to be emphasized.

Answer (score 29):

To do type checking at runtime with an interface is using [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), if interfaces you wish to check have **different** properties/functions.

Example

```
let pet = getSmallPet();

if ((pet as Fish).swim) {
    (pet as Fish).swim();
} else if ((pet as Bird).fly) {
    (pet as Bird).fly();
}
```

Comment: What if I learn about ducks and add the function swim() to my Bird interface? Would't every pet be classified as fish in a type guard?

And if I have three interface with three functions each and two overlap with one of the other interfaces?

Comment: @Kayz if you don't have properties/functions that uniquely identify an interface, you can't really differentiate them. Your pet that could be actually a `Duck`, you type guard it becomes `Fish`, but still no runtime exception when you invoke `swim()`. Suggest you create 1 level of common interface (e.g. `Swimmable`) and move you `swim()` functions there, then type guard still looks good with `((pet as Swimmable).swim`.

Comment: To prevent typecasting you can use `'swim' in pet` condition. It will narrow it down to a subset that has to have `swim` defined (ex: `Fish | Mammal`)

Answer (score 4):

When it is about checking if an object conforms to an interface signature, then I think the appropriate approach is considering using "type predicates":
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Rosenwasser might be right and dandy but i feel like doing an amendment to his answer. It is fully possible to check instance of x, see the code snippet.

But it's equally easy to assign x = y. Now x would not be an instance of C as y only had the shape of C.

```
class C {
a: number = 10;
b: boolean = true;
c: string = "hello";
}

let x = new C()
let y = {
    a: 10, b: true, c: "hello",
}

console.log('x is C? ' + (x instanceof C)) // return true
console.log('y is C? ' + (y instanceof C)) // return false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the in operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) for checking if the element you need is in the object.

With this method, you can verify if x is a string or Foo

```
if ('abcdef' in x) {
    // x is instance of Foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is usually the correct answer.

In my case however, I was working with a primitive type and both `instanceof Number` and `instanceof number` errored in the ts compiler:

```
TS2322: Type 'Number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

```
TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

`typeof` is the correct answer when primitive types are in use:

```
if (typeof value === 'number') {this.propertyValue = value}
```