# useRef "refers to a value, but is being used as a type here."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to tell react which element is being used as ref i.e. in my case

```
const circleRef = useRef<AnimatedCircle>(undefined);
```

`AnimatedCircle` is an SVG component from a third party library, and defining it this way causes error

[image]

Is there some universal way to define which element is ref?

Comment: Can you share the definitions of useRef and AnimatedCircle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 'instanceof' in TypeScript give me the error "'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703364/why-does-instanceof-in-typescript-give-me-the-error-foo-only-refers-to-a-ty)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`AnimatedCircle` is a *function*, not a type. This means it cannot be used in TypeScript in place of a type, like in the generic constraint of `useRef`. Instead, you need to use the `typeof operator` to convert to a type:

```
const circleRef = useRef<typeof AnimatedCircle | null>(null);
```

Comment: Constructor functions are typically types too, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, but since the OP states that `AnimatedCircle` is a component type and they are getting this error I'm willing to bet it's a function and not a class.

Comment: Unfortunate name for one, if it's not a constructor, as it breaks the basic naming rule of JavaScript/TypeScript. :-)

Comment: In React, all component types are conventionally TitleCase. Lower case names are used to distinguish between native DOM elements (`div`, `x-your-name-here`, etc) and custom React components (`AnimatedCircle`). While it breaks the convention of *javascript* / *typescript*, it is the convention in React mostly because there's no other non-clumsy way to make React work with custom elements and/or new tags

Comment: Oh, I'm v. familiar with that, I'm just used to thinking of them as constructors. But of course, functional components aren't, from TypeScript's type perspective, constructors, and with hooks basically all components become functional ones. Bit of a pain, I expect it'll get addressed. :-)

Comment: What is the `| null` for?

Comment: @raarts late reply, sorry! if you used strict null checking in typescript, passing `null` to `useRef` wasn't (isn't?) without explicitly adding it in the type signature and would result in a type error. `useRef<typeof AnimatedCircle>(null);` would fail because null is not assignable to `typeof AnimatedCircle`

Answer (score 99):

In my case, I renamed the file as `.ts` instead of `.tsx`. Renaming it again fixed it.

Comment: man, all my trouble was this mistake! tanks, you just fixed my situation, 3h into searching all the internet about this.

Comment: I was just getting ready to throw my computer out a window — thank you!! The file extension was the last place I was gonna look

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error in

```
ReactDOM.render(
<App store={store} persistor={persistor} basename={PUBLIC_URL} />,
document.getElementById("root");
```

And I renamed the file to `.tsx` and that fixed the problem. The reason is that, when you are using `React` or `ReactDOM`, you have to rename file to `.tsx` instead of `ts`. For `JavaScript`, `.js` works but for `TypeScript`, `.ts` don't work.

Comment: There is a similar question with the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341545/navbar-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-when-trying-to-rend

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I tried to import a type and used it to extend a type:

`import type ResultMap form...`

tried to do `Promise<typeof ResultMap>`

But this if not working, because

> It’s important to note that classes have a value at runtime and a type at design-time, and the use is context-sensitive. When using import type to import a class, you can’t do things like extend from it.
> (Source: [ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export))