# How to solve refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof DatePicker'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I use ReactJs with TypeScript and AntDesign and i have problem.

I've got the function which return AntDesignComponent, but typeScript throw error.

**'TextArea' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof TextArea'?ts(2749)**

**The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)**

**The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)**

**Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Input' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)**

```
export const getTypeFormElem = ({
  type = 'input',
  typeValue = 'text',
  ...props
}) => {
  if (type === 'textarea') return <TextArea value='123' { ...props } />;
  if (type === 'checkbox') return <Checkbox { ...props } />;
  if (type === 'date') return <DatePicker { ...props } />;
  return <Input type={ typeValue } {...props } />;
};
```

[import components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbw8J.png)

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTRiQ.png)

Can u explain how to solve this problem and whats wrong i do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Navbar refers to a value, but is being used as a type here" when trying to render a shallow copy of my component when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341545/navbar-refers-to-a-value-but-is-being-used-as-a-type-here-when-trying-to-rend)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should name your file `.tsx` and not `.ts` because you have JSX in it…