# Function argument with two possible types in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I have a function with an argument. This argument needs to be one of two kind of interfaces.
So i write it like this:

```
 add(item: IntDroga | IntSolucion){
  if(item && item.identificacion){
   if(item.estado.habilitada.value == false || item.estado.estado == estadoAprobacion.Aprobado){ 
    // some code
   }
  }
 }
```

But i recieve the following error.

```
    Property 'habilitada' does not exist on type '{ estado: string; habilitada: { value: boolean; viewValue: string; }; excluida: boolean; } | { estado: estadoAprobacion; fecha: Date; usuario: string; }'.
  Property 'habilitada' does not exist on type '{ estado: estadoAprobacion; fecha: Date; usuario: string; }'.ts(2339)
```

Here are the interfaces:

IntDroga:

```
export interface IntDroga {
    _id: string;
    identificacion: {
            nombre: string,
            codigo: string,
            marca: string,
            grupoSustancias: string,
            nProducto: string,
            lote: string,
            CAS: string,
            codigoAlternativo: string,
            estandarInterno: boolean
    };
    informacion: {
            pureza: number,
            humedad: number,
            fecha: {
                    fabricacion: Date,
                    recepcion: Date,
                    vencimientoCertificado: Date,
                    vencimientoAsignada: Date,
            },
            presentacion: string,
            solucion?: { concentracion: number, unidad: string},
            cantidad: {
                    recibida: {valor: number, unidad: string},
                    remanente: {valor: number, unidad: string},
                    unidad: string,
            },
            concentracion?: {valor: number, unidad: string},
            DLDC: {
                    libre: {value: boolean, viewValue: string},
                    masaDL: number,
                    masaDC: number,
                    fDLDC: number,
            };
            sectores: string [];
            rubros: string [];
            ubicacion: string;
            observaciones: string;
    };
    estado: {
            estado: string,
            habilitada: {value: boolean, viewValue: string},
            excluida: boolean
    };
}
```

IntSolucion:

```
export interface IntSolucion {
_id: string,
identificacion: {
    nombre: string,
    codigo: string,
},
informacion:{
    tipo: string,
    componentes: Componente [] ,
    fecha:{
        preparacion: Date,
        vencimiento: Date,
        descarte: Date
    },
    material:{
        matraz: {
            codigo: string,
            volumen: {value: number, unidad: string}
        }
    },
    temperaturaPreparacion: string,
    almacenamiento: string
    analista: string,
    solvente: {tipo: string, identificacion: string}
},
estado?: {estado:estadoAprobacion, fecha: Date, usuario: string};
};
```

I can´t undestand what´s the problems. It is supposed that the function´s argument can have two different structures. I don´t know why Tslink marks it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should take a look at typescrit typeguard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: That's because `IntSolucion` doesn't have the property `habilitada` in the field `estado`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the *IntSolucion* doesn't have the property "habilitada" on "estado" object. Maybe, you can change to this:

```
add(item: IntDroga | IntSolucion){
  if(item && item.identificacion){
    if(((item instaceof IntDroga) && item.estado.habilitada.value == false) || item.estado.estado == estadoAprobacion.Aprobado) { 
     // some code
    }
  }
}
```

Another approach is do some type condition:

```
if (item instanceof IntDroga) {
  // do the stuff assuming an IntDrog instance
} else {
  // do the stuff assuming an IntSolucion instance
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your help, so in typescript i can  write `(item: IntDroga | IntSolucion)` saying that item can have the structure of one of those interfaces but anyway in the code below i have to continue differentiating the code for each case?

Comment: Yes, you need to differentiate. Thinking about the javascript translation, if during execution the item is an instance of IntSolucion, the execution will throw an exception "cannot read property value of undefined" (because "habilitada" is undefined). If you use the first approach or use `item.estado.habilitada?.value` (look the ? character) you may not receive the error but I think tslink will continue to mark it.

Comment: Understood, the problem i have now is that whith this approach `if (item instanceof IntDroga)` i get the error `'IntDroga' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Comment: I see, it's because IntDroga is an Interface, not a Class, right? You cannot do that with interfaces because interfaces are removed on compilation. Maybe with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46703380/5264995).